# The application may be doing too much work on its main thread in android studio

Tags: java, android, ksoap2, netbeans-8

I have created a webservice class in netbeans and want to call this webservice in Android Studio

1) here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app.shrutivyas.newwebserviceexample" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:maxSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name="com.app.shrutivyas.newwebserviceexample.MyNewWebService"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

2) here is my class MyNewWebService.java

```
public class MyNewWebService extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText edoperand1,edoperand2,edoperator;
Button btnsubmit;
TextView txtResult;

//initialization of methods,action,namespace and URLWS using SOAP
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://WSUtility/Additionoperation";
private static final String SOAP_ACTIONSubtraction = "http://WSUtility/SubtractionOperation";
private static final String SOAP_ACTIONMultiplication = "http://WSUtility/MultiplicationOperation";
private static final String SOAP_ACTIONDivision = "http://WSUtility/DivisionOperation";

private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Additionoperation";
private static final String METHOD_NAMESubtraction = "SubtractionOperation";
private static final String METHOD_NAMEMultiplication = "MultiplicationOperation";
private static final String METHOD_NAMEDivision = "DivisionOperation";

private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://WSUtility/";
private static final String URLWS = "http://192.168.1.61:8080/GlassFishArithmaticOperations/GlassFishArithmaticOperations?wsdl";

 int intOperand1,intOperand2;
Context context;
private static String Result="Result String";
private static int Result1;

private SoapObject request;
private PropertyInfo propertyInfo1;
private PropertyInfo propertyInfo2;

Handler handler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_new_web_service);
    context=this;
    edoperand1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edOper1);
    edoperand2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edOper2);
    edoperator=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edOperator1);
    btnsubmit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    txtResult=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult);


    btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            intOperand1 =Integer.parseInt(edoperand1.getText().toString());
            intOperand2 = Integer.parseInt(edoperand2.getText().toString());
            String stringOperator = edoperator.getText().toString();

            MathOperationsAsyncTask mathOperationsAsyncTask = new   MathOperationsAsyncTask(intOperand1, intOperand2,stringOperator );
            mathOperationsAsyncTask.execute();

    }
});
}

private class MathOperationsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    int number1;
    int number2;
    String operation;

    MathOperationsAsyncTask (int number1, int number2, String opertion){
      this.number1 = number1;
        this.number2 = number2;
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    String errorMessage="";
    protected String doInBackground(String... URLs) {
        try {
        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("eOperand1", number1);
        request.addProperty("eOperand2", number2);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttPTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URLWS);
        //androidHttPTransport.debug=true;

            androidHttPTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            //String response1=androidHttPTransport.responseDump;
            //Log.d("response in xml : ",response);
            //request=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            //final Object response=envelope.getResponse();
            Result1=Integer.parseInt(response.toString());
            Result = response.toString();

        }
        catch(Exception ee) {
            errorMessage=ee.getMessage();
        }

        return Result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Exception is : " + errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        txtResult.setText(Result);
        txtResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(context, "String Result : " + Result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Integer Result : " + Result1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

3) here is my layout.xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MyNewWebService">


<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Enter Operand1" android:id="@+id/edOper1"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Enter Operand2" android:id="@+id/edOper2"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Enter Operator" android:id="@+id/edOperator1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txtResult" android:visibility="invisible" android:text="Result"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btnSubmit" android:text="Submit" />
```

4) and lastly logcat shows

```
I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11345: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V

D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11351: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method        
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 568 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 235K, 10% free 2876K/3188K, paused 14ms, total 20ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 406K, 15% free 2967K/3460K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 1271 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 1305 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

i am not getting an error but.
I am getting 0 as an output and server response is null

Comment: Are you getting any error or the app frozen while executing your asynctask?

Comment: No i am not getting an error

Comment: Didn't get you right response from server?

Comment: Ok then you need to add breakpoints and debug your app

Comment: i debug the application many times but still didn't get the problem

Comment: Have you printed `Result`  in your Log?

Comment: no, I have set Result in TextView and also display it using Toast message

Comment: Are you running your app in emulator or device?

Comment: I am running this app in emulator

Comment: If this is your demo project then able to send code to me because u r saying there is no any error so it is hard to tell you exactly whats happening there.

Comment: have u received project .zip link ?

Comment: Yeah i received just downloading it..

Comment: Are you working with Android Studio?? And yes you can now delete your drive link comment.

Comment: whether i also put my webservice NetBeans application in oneDrive?

Comment: yes i am working on Android Studio

Comment: Oh... I haven't tried yet AS though try to solve your issue. Before that please run your app again and print your server url in log and show me that url in which your response is.

Comment: Server URL means response in XML?

Comment: Yes.... Right. that is...

Comment: code : String response1=androidHttPTransport.responseDump; , response1 is null